# Ternary syntax for if elsif in rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ternary-operator

I am attempting to check the value of an element (status) and perform and if elsif statement on it. If the status is approved I want to add html and if it is rejected I want to add different html. I had attempted:

```
%td= campaign.status == "Approved" ?  '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success"></span>'.html_safe || campaign.status == "Rejected" ? '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-success"></span>'.html_safe
```

But it is failing. Works okay with the basic if statement as shown below:

```
%td= campaign.status == "Approved" ?  '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success"></span>'.html_safe : campaign.status
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: "But is failing"? What does that mean? syntax error? something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general syntax for rub ternary operator:

```
test-expression ? if-true-expression : if-false-expression
```

In your example, try this:

```
%td= campaign.status == "Approved" ?  '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success"></span>'.html_safe : campaign.status || campaign.status == "Rejected" ? '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-success"></span>'.html_safe : campaign.status
```

Answer (score 1):

Ternary operator syntax is

`e1` ? `e2` : `e3`

You can't not have the `: e3` part